# Trouble displaying vector labels

Tags: openlayers

I want to display the labels for each feature, but I get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: Style is not defined" error. How do I fix it correctly?

```
     var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([102.291163, 12.809588]),
            zoom: 9
        })
    });
    var labelStyle = new Style({
        text: new Text({
            font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
            overflow: true,
            fill: new Fill({
            color: '#000'
            }),
            stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3
            })
        })
    });

    var tambonStyle = new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#319FD3',
            width: 1
        })
    });

    var style = [tambonStyle, labelStyle];

    var layer_source = new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'geojson/tambon_wgs84.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    });

    var layer_tambon = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: layer_source,
        style: function(features) {
            labelStyle.getText().setText(features.get('TAM_NAM_T'));
            return style;
        },
        declutter: true
    });

    map.addLayer(layer_tambon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using complete OpenLayers `ol.js` library, you have to use appropriate calls that start with `ol.` for all the modules. This is easy to forget when you copy code from OpenLayers official examples, which use `import` for individual modules.

In your case this would be:

- `ol.style.Style`
- `ol.style.Text`
- `ol.style.Fill`
- `ol.style.Stroke`

Comment: Thank you TomazicM. I will remember about your suggestions.